# Running and saving a cognos report?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cognos, connection

I am trying to run a cognos report by passing parameters to it (date inputs) from python so I can load them into a dataframe in pandas. Would this be possible?

Comment: You can pass parameters to cognos via url, so just try send get request via python.

Comment: Check this URL:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21338766